# RStudio 0.97.551 shows unrecognizable characters in console

Tags: r, encoding, rstudio

Sometimes Rstudio I am using shows unrecognizable characters in console like in the following pic:
[image]

I tried the same command in R console and it seems it shows normally:
[image]

What is wrong with my Rstudio?  How to solve it? I tried to set text encoding in Rstudio as WINDOWS-1252 and UTF-8. They didn't work.
**It seems it is the single quotation mark's problem.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try My Computer -> Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Administrative -> Language for non-unicode programs -> Change whatever it is to English(US)

Comment: If I change that, Chinese characters in many programs will not display correctly.

Comment: That's true. Haven't found a way to solve both problems.